# How can I use Firebase Admin SDK in my Angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

How can I use Firebase Admin SDK in my Angular application?

I currently have an application that is implementing the Firebase Authentication authentication services, all I currently need to register, authenticate a user is in [Angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md).

I've been seeing and the Firebase Admin SDK can not be used on the front end I would have to create a back end using Node.js configuring as Introduction to the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?hl=pt-br#add_firebase_to_your_app) loading a file with the credentials of my project.

I have been trying to `import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';` directly into a service file but I have a return with several errors due to how Firebase Admin should be implemented.

To delete a user I use Cloud Functions, I check when the user is deleted in the database and then I also exclude in Firebase Authentication.

I use Firebase Hosting to upload my application, I wonder if I can use [Express.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and if I can not, what I can use to make use of all the [User Management](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?hl=pt-br) functions through Admin SDK to Node.js in my Angular application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Express.JS for exposing REST APIs that your Angular App is going to consume. But generally, your Firebase Cloud Functions can also be considered as REST APIs of POST type.

I've used Firebase's Admin SDK for User Management itself. One of the use cases where I was stuck using AngularFire2 was when I wanted to add users to my App using an Admin Panel in my App.

Whenever I tried to add the user by calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method on AngularFire2, it logged me out and created a session for the user that I intended on creating. To tackle that, I created an HTTP Cloud Function. This Cloud Function acted as a POST API for me to send users details and get it created on the Realtime Database.

Comment: So you create a function in Cloud Functions to receive POST calls and do what you need?

Comment: Exactly. You can do that. I recommend you reading this:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

If like me, videos is your thing then you can check these out:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: Thank you for asking my question.

Answer (score 2):

Just include **firebase-admin**, You can use the following snippet to work with any javascript client, make sure its deployed at secure place and no one having access to its serviceAccountKey.json

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://kiraye-pay-stage.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Thanks